# Git cannot clone repository into CIFS mounted directory

Tags: linux, git, mount, cifs

Attempting to clone a remote Git repository into a CIFS mounted directory on Linux.

The error is:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@github.com/ghuser/ghuser.git dir
Cloning into 'dir'...
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/user/dir/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Some potentially relevant information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux myfarms-dev 3.12.0-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 6 09:06:27 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/fstab
...
//192.168.56.1/Code /home/user/dir cifs users,exec,noauto,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=http,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0

$ umask
0002
```

This exact same process works for most of our developers (i.e. mounting a Windows share in Linux and cloning the repository into it), but not for this one in particular. Any ideas?

Edit: Steps I have taken so far: Updated packages, remounted file share, checked permissions on the directory on the Windows side (full access to the user). The error initially occurred during a git fetch inside an existing repository. Git (or something) seemed to be creating tmp_pack files without u+w permission, despite the umask. I deleted the entire local repository and started anew, which resulted in the above error during clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tests and searching I find 2 options:

1. Downgrade kernel to version 3.11.6
2. Launch git commands with sudo. (https://superuser.com/a/121854/275562)